# Angular 2 component style is being applied globally

Tags: angular, sass, styles, webpack-2

I am trying to use component specific style only for that component but it is being used in all others component. I have webpack setup. I tried different approach but it's not working as expected. Can anyone help me to figure this out.
Webpack configuration:

```
    /*
     * to string and css loader support for *.css files
     * Returns file content as string
     *
     */
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    /*
     * to string and css loader support for *.css files
     * Returns file content as string
     *
     */
    {
      test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
      use: ['to-string-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    },
```

My component declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'outbreak-visualization',
  templateUrl: './outbreak-visualization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./outbreak-visualization.component.scss']
})
```

My app component declaration

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.global.scss'
  ],
  template: `.....
```

Comment: make sure component specifuc styles are not being over written by global styles

Comment: Well, you are configuring your application with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. This means that all your styles are not encapsulated. Delete this line and add your global styles in the `.angular-cli.json` in the section `styles: [...]`.

Comment: It is not overwritten but I can see all styles in every page as: <style type="text/css">/*styles for home content only*/
body {
  color: #105cb6; }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
 /*!
 * File: outbreak.component
 * Created on:  10/6/17.
 */
</style>
<style type="text/css">
/*!
 * File: outbreak-details.component
 * Created on:  10/11/17.
 */
#map {
  height: 100%; }

main {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body, html {
  height: 100%; }
</style>
@Danielomi :Not using .angular-cli.json but webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

i have global scss file in the following location :

src => app => app.component.global.scss

**app.component.global.scss**

```
body {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

and i have style.scss file in the following location :

**style.scss**

```
@import "src/app/app.component.global.scss";
```

add your style.scss inside the styles array in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss"
]
```